# Commandlet vs Console App

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I'm looking for guidance/documentation on when to build a custom PowerShell CMDLet vs. a console application and am wondering whether there are specific boundaries where using a CMDLet is ill adviced. To make this question more concrete (and answerable) here's my scenario:

I'm trying to solve for scriptable data import, the import is done against a platform that provides with webservices which allows me to read/write data.

I have the following (high level) requirements:

- Call the webservices and retrieve data to check whether the imported data exists (and perhaps requires an update)
- Read (csv) import files of a max size 25MB
- Read complex XML mapping files max size 2MB
- Needs to be scriptable (used for automated deployment, part of an automated build process)

I have now doubt that with a CMDLet I can do all these things, but I'm wondering if an CMDLet is the right option here. I'm looking for an answer to my particular situation, but since I'm just getting started with CMDLets I'd very much appreciate additional information on how to make a choice here.

Comment: Why not provide the solution as a PS Module, using advanced functions?

Comment: mjolnor that's what I was going for, I'm probably building a module that allows for the import with some simple parameters. Thanks for correcting my verbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, the're only two times when it's not ok to build a CMDlet

1. You need to build it fast and it just needs to work, (short on time), or don't have a lot of staff on hand who know how to use powershell.
2. You need the scriptable import to be cross platform via Mono-Project on Linux/Mac etc.

Aside from that I think the flexibility powershell gives you makes building a CMDlet a no brainer.

If you build your import logic as a CMDLet in an importable powershell module you can leverage the entire .net framework in a powershell script against your CMDlet.

In powershell, you get some of your requirements right out of the gate.

1. CSV Files, powershell can pipe CSV files without you having to code anything there
2. XML Files, powershell can also pipe XML
3. Scriptable: Powershell is a scripting engine.
4. Calling a WebService: [Powershell can also call web services](http://blog.robseder.com/2014/03/23/calling-a-soap-web-service-from-powershell-3-0/)

Powershell was designed to be a better alternative to building console applications for command lines.  So in my opinion, it's never really a bad idea to leverage the power of powershell.

In fact, you can run the entire powershell framework in a console app turning your console app into a powershell command line, and it's pretty easy to implement.

[Writing a Powershell Host Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706563%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Our database project uses powershell on it's import logic via a custom module. Allowing me to do things like,

1. Migrate-Employees -source LegacyProd -destination Prod
2. Migrate-All -source LegacyProd -destination Prod
3. XYZDB-GetEmployee -EmployeeID 603
4. XYZDB-GetCustomer -CustomerID 000567
5. XYZDB-GetCustomer | Select CustomerID, Name, Address | Out-File c:\customerDump.txt

Etc, however notice #5 This is what makes powershell awesome.  In #5 I get a dump of all of our customers selecting only their CustomerID, Name, and Address and dump them to a text file for referrence.  I didn't have to code anything but the GetCustomer CmdLet, the rest is all powershell features.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I'll probably build a module to do the import as there's an SDK with some optimizations available for the import and web API. This SDK is common across servers/services in this case so it's not bad to have these dependencies. It looks like there aren't any concerns about a CMDLet doing "too much" or any technical limitations. You've set me on a better path than I was on with those examples.

Comment: One thin you need to consider though is if you want to support powershell 2, or just version 3.

In version 3 the way you build a module is different than in version 2.  E.g. in Version 2 you actually register your dll as a SnapIn with Add-PSSnapIn.  In Version 3 you can design your stuff as a module and use Import-Module.  If every server your working with has (or can have installed) version 3, I'd go with that.